# Check if cifar10 is converted well

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Recently I followed a few tutorials on machine learning, and now I want to test if I can make some image recognition program by myself. For this I want to use the [CIFAR 10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) dataset, but I think I have a small problem in the conversion of the dataset.

For who is not familiar with this set: the dataset comes as lists of n rows and 3072 columns, in which the first 1024 columns represent the red values, the second 1024 the green values and the last are the blue values. Each row is a single image (size 32x32) and the pixel rows are stacked after each other (first 32 values are the red values for the top-most row of pixels, etc.)

What I wanted to do with this dataset is to transform it to a 4D tensor (with numpy), so I can view the images with matplotlibs `.imshow()`. the tensor I made has this shape: `(n, 32, 32, 3)`, so the first 'dimension' stores all images, the second stores rows of pixels, the third stores individual pixels and the last represents the rgb values of those pixels. Here is the function I made that should do this:

```
def rawToRgb(data):
    length = data.shape[0]

    # convert to flat img array with rgb pixels
    newAr = np.zeros([length, 1024, 3])
    for img in range(length):
        for pixel in range(1024):
            newAr[img, pixel, 0] = data[img, pixel]
            newAr[img, pixel, 1] = data[img, pixel+1024]
            newAr[img, pixel, 2] = data[img, pixel+2048]

    # convert to 2D img array
    newAr2D = newAr.reshape([length, 32, 32, 3])
    # plt.imshow(newAr2D[5998])
    # plt.show()
    return newAr2D
```

Which takes a single parameter (a tensor of shape `(n, 3072)`). I have commented out the pyplot code, as this is only for testing, but when testing, I noticed that everything seems to be ok (I can recognise the shapes of the objects in the images, but I am not sure if the colours are good or not, as I get some oddly-coloured images as well as some pretty normal images... Here are a few examples: [purple plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzJ0T.png), [blue cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQnD9.png), [normal horse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB9Uv.png), [blue frog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMs2N.png).

Can anyone tell me wether I am making a mistake or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images that appear oddly-coloured are the [negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_(photography)) of the actual image, so you need to subtract each pixel value from 255 to get the true value. If you simply want to see what the original images look like, use:

```
from scipy.misc import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = imread(file_path)
plt.imshow(255 - img)
plt.show()
```

The original cause of the problem is that the CIFAR-10 data stores the pixel values on a scale of 0-255, but matplotlib's `imshow()` method (which I assume you are using) expects inputs between 0 and 1. Given an input that is not scaled between 0 and 1, `imshow()` does some normalization internally, which causes some images to become negatives.